# I tried to write a reload script but my logic wasn't good enough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-development

```cs
IEnumerator Reload(float reloadSpeed)
{
    canShoot = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadSpeed);
    if(totalAmmo >= magazineCapacity)
    {
        totalAmmo -= magazineCapacity - currentAmmo;
        currentAmmo += magazineCapacity - currentAmmo;
    }
    else if(totalAmmo <= magazineCapacity && (totalAmmo -= magazineCapacity - (magazineCapacity - totalAmmo) - currentAmmo) > 0 )
    {
        totalAmmo -=  magazineCapacity - (magazineCapacity - totalAmmo) - currentAmmo;
        currentAmmo += magazineCapacity - (magazineCapacity - totalAmmo) - currentAmmo; 
        
    }
    else
    {
        if(totalAmmo + currentAmmo <= magazineCapacity)
        {
            currentAmmo += totalAmmo;
            totalAmmo = 0;                  
        }
        else
        {
            int leftAmmo;
            leftAmmo = totalAmmo + currentAmmo - magazineCapacity;
            currentAmmo = totalAmmo - leftAmmo;
            totalAmmo = leftAmmo;
        }
    }
    canShoot = true;
}
```

So when my ammo that isn't reloaded yet is less than 30 I can't reload and it starts to do random stuff like evening my currentAmmo and totalAmmo or leveling my totalAmmo don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a case for every possibility when reloading, this should be a more generic solution. `Mathf.Clamp` will stop you from drawing more ammo from total ammo than you have.

```
IEnumerator Reload(float reloadSpeed)
{
    canShoot = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadSpeed);

    // No ammo? No reload
    if (totalAmmo > 0)
    {
        //Take out the amount of ammo we need. Clamp the amount so that we cant take more than the total ammo
        int amountToWithdraw = Mathf.Clamp(magazineCapacity - currentAmmo, 0, magazineCapacity); 
        totalAmmo -= amountToWithdraw;
        currentAmmo += amountToWithdraw;
    }

    canShoot = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've been working on it for a day and couldn't figure out how to write it. This helped a lot.

Comment: Just nedden to change the 
int amountToWithdraw = Mathf.Clamp(magazineCapacity - currentAmmo, totalAmmo, magazineCapacity); 
to:
int amountToWithdraw = Mathf.Clamp(magazineCapacity - currentAmmo, 1, magazineCapacity);

Comment: @DenizTuncerTepe Oh yea I see, won't it be better if its set to 0 instead of 1? That way its stops it going to negative values?